# Проблемы с float на отрезке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой код. Нужно, чтобы все три переменные подходили под отрезки, но когда ввожу, то ничего не происходит. Как правильно сделать?

```
print('P1 = ?')
p1 = float(input())
print('P2 = ?')
p2 = float(input())
print('Pk = ?')
pk = float(input())


if -0.90 < p1 < -0.94 and -0.14 < p2 < -0.17 and 28 < pk < 32:
    print("Верно")
print('Programm end')
```

Comment: Тут скорее вопрос про float...
Если бы были бы int, то всё работало

Comment: Нет, ничего бы не работало. У Вас невозможные условия

Answer (score 2):

`-0.90 < p1 < -0.94` означает, что p1 > -0.90 и p1 < -0.94, чего быть не может, потому что не может быть никогда :) Правильно поставленные условия должны быть

```
-0.94 < p1 < -0.90
```

если во всех  трех случаях поменять числа местами, всё заработает

Answer (score 1):

```
p1 = float(input('P1 = ? :'))
p2 = float(input('P2 = ? :'))
pk = float(input('Pk = ? :'))

if (-0.94 < p1 < -0.90) and (-0.17 < p2 < -0.14) and (28 < pk < 32):
    print("Верно")
else:
    print('Не верно')
```